# Div reloading jquery and passing PHP variables with it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For some strange reason this doesn't seem to work, I tried to use static vars like this but would work until I moved it out of the isset 'test'. I think this has to do with it not being able to pass on get data like this?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['test'])) 
{
?>Hey<?php  $count='1'; echo $count;
} 
?>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<div id="main">
    <a><div id="dialogue" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">Click to continue</div></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
    $('#dialogue').click(function(){
        $('#main').load('dialogue.php?test&count=<?php echo $count ?>', function() {
            // can add another function here
        });
    });
}); // End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>
```

Comment: do you have `test` set in your query string?

Comment: $('#main').load('dialogue.php?test&count=<?php echo $count ?>', function() {

Comment: I am trying to pass it on as you can see

Comment: You forgot a `;` on that line.

Comment: `$count` is always 1. `<?php $count='1'; echo $count;`

Comment: Ofcourse, but not even that is getting passed on, I choose to use static variables to test. Look into the source code and the &count= will be empty

Comment: Are these two separate files?

Comment: No, as you can see its in the top of the file....

Comment: Fixed it myself, I worked it out with session

Comment: If he's using a session now, he probably still doesn't know why it was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Definition for load

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
```

Try with data, like this example at https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#objectID" ).load( "test.php", { "choices[]": [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```